# Setting a div style using Angular JS compatibility error with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm working on a website where I use Angular JS to show the DataBase. One of the things that I should show is a custom ProgressBar made with 2 divs, but the problem is that I use the $scope to set the width (*style="width: {{project.funded}}%"*). It works on Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome, but Internet Explorer doesn't recognize it and sets the *width to auto*, as shown in the Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqSqD.png  (On Internet Explorer is always the same progress although the number is different)

The code:

```
<div ng-if="project.funded >= 8" class="funded_bar2" style="width:{{project.funded}}%">
   <div>
       <p class="text_funded">
          {{project.funded | number:0}}%
       </p>
       <img ng-if="project.funded < 100" 
            src="resources/img/fundedbar.png" 
            class="image_funded" />
       <img ng-if="project.funded >= 100" 
            src="resources/img/overfundedbar.png" 
            class="image_funded" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to solve this compatibility problem?

Comment: Not sure what is happening here but have you tried using ng-style instead? This is the preferred method. Try ng-style="{'width': project.funded + '%'}" and let me know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, it perfectly works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE will try to preparse the style, before Angular gets there; the same way that `<img src="{{ }}">` would try to load, before angular replaced it.

When IE sees the invalid CSS, it discards the style statement (so Angular has nothing to read).

The solution is to use `ng-style="{'property':value}"`, much like you'd use `ng-src`, `ng-href`, `ng-attr-<name>`, etc.